# How can bulk download images on a webpage AND save their respective urls?

Tags: download, pictures, bulk

I know they are quite a few tools to bulk download pictures from webpages, but I need to do something a bit different.

I'm building a website that curates images found around the web.

So instead of only downloading images, I also need to have a saved file with all the urls of the pages where the original image can be found, so that I can link to the original resources.

There is this one tool whose name I forgot that does almost that, although it saves the server path of the image, which is unsuitable because most of the times, images are hosted on a CDN, and I need to be able to link to the original page, not hotlinking their CDN.

Do you guys know a method to do that ?

Comment: At the cost of complexity, this sounds like it could be workable with the command line (a script that both retrieves the data in question and uses the places the URL in a list of some sort along with the file name).